# How To Find Unique Numbers from 3 Numbers

Tags: logic

If I have 3 numbers, how can I find one number that is unique to that combination.

E.g. (4, 3, 5) has a unique number that is not the same as (5, 3, 4).

I tried adding a number to each component (like 1 to x, 2, y, and 3 to z and then multiplying that number, but there were a lot of problems with this).

Comment: Are you trying to find a mapping, `(a, b, c)->n` where every unique triple `(a, b, c)` maps to a unique `n`?  If a, b, and c are integers, then that will be possible, but it's going to be more of an algorithm than a mathematical _function_.

Comment: Jim, you are exactly right. And it will be an algorithm!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your numbers are non-negative; other options can be accommodated. The boring way is to use the mapping $(x,y,z) \mapsto 2^x3^y5^z$, but the resulting numbers are somewhat big. Another option is to use
$$
(x,y,z) \mapsto \binom{x}{1} + \binom{x+y+1}{2} + \binom{x+y+z+2}{3}.
$$
This mapping has the distinction that it is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}^3$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Simple yet genius. Thank you!

Comment: Your second mapping is beautiful (assuming it actually works.  I am too much of a piker to attempt to prove it.)  I just wanted to point out that since $\mathbb{Z}\mapsto\mathbb{N}$ is possible, your second example can be made to work for all integers, not just for positive integers.

Comment: Will this work with floats/fractions/non-integers?

Comment: @wwii It won't. It isn't designed to.